# Django ORM giving inconsistent response between 'get' and 'filter'

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I used [Django-softdelete](https://github.com/scoursen/django-softdelete) to undelete an entry from table 'QRMapping'(using Django admin panel). Now when I perform `QRMapping.objects.get(qrid=myqr)` where `qrid` is a foreign key field of `QRMapping` and `myqr` is a variable having entry of another table `MyQR` the result is correct i.e.

```
<< QRMapping: QRMapping object>>
```

But when I perform `QRMapping.objects.filter(qrid=myqr)` it returns empty list

```
[]
```

If `get` is returning an entry then why is 'filter' not able to find it.

Comment: It looks like might be hitting [this issue](https://github.com/scoursen/django-softdelete/issues/9).

Comment: I am not sure about this. Above issue refer to those cases where `get` is returning soft-deleted items. In my case the entry is restored after deletion (corresponding entry in `Change sets` table of soft-delete is removed as mentioned in docs). Hence, here un-deleted entry is not being shown by `filter` as compared to deleted entry wrongfully shown by `get` in your link.